# Foreign Keys, Joins, and returning the Index

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, left-join

I have two tables in a mySQL database.

- milestones_all (PRIMARY KEY: MSID)
- user_transactions (FOREIGN KEY: MSID)

I am using the following code to query the tables:

```
   $get_ms = db_query("SELECT * FROM milestones_all
        LEFT JOIN user_transactions on user_transactions.MSID = milestones_all.MSID 
        WHERE milestones_all.MID=$MID  
        AND (user_transactions.tran_status IS NULL OR user_transactions.tran_status=3)
        ORDER BY milestones_all.MSID ASC LIMIT 1"));

    while($ms = $get_ms->fetch_assoc()){
           $MSID = $ms['MSID'];
           $ms_title = $ms['ms_title'];
     }
```

Here is just the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM milestones_all
LEFT JOIN user_transactions on user_transactions.MSID = milestones_all.MSID 
WHERE milestones_all.MID=$MID
AND (user_transactions.tran_status IS NULL OR user_transactions.tran_status=3)
ORDER BY milestones_all.MSID ASC LIMIT 1
```

What I am trying to do is print out the data from `milestones_all` for any row that either 
doesn't have a `user_transactions` row attached to it or, if it does, the column `tran_status` in `user_transactions` is set to `3`.

As of now, the query returns the proper results regarding which rows to return. `ms_title` is returned exactly how is should be. The problem is: `MSID` always returns blank. It is not blank in my database. Could this be because the `LEFT JOIN` is using the `MSID` column to find matches? Maybe there is a totally better way to do this?

Note: the `db_query` function does not interfere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because you have two columns named `MSID`.  If you change the join to use `USING` instead of `ON`, it will collapse the two columns into one:

```
SELECT * FROM milestones_all
LEFT JOIN user_transactions USING(MSID) 
WHERE milestones_all.MID=$MID
AND (user_transactions.tran_status IS NULL OR user_transactions.tran_status=3)
ORDER BY milestones_all.MSID ASC LIMIT 1
```